# How to make a HTML content inside ToolTip inside a table row function

Tags: html, css, tooltip, zurb-foundation

I am trying to make a tooltip display when hovering over a row with a large amount of HTML content inside. This is used in conjunction with Foundation. I cannot get the tooltip to function when a row is being used in the HTML. Thanks

HTML

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="hover>
      <div class=" tooltip ">asdadasd
      </div>
      <td>nothing </td>
      <td>nothing</td>
      <td>nothing</td>
      <td>nothing</td>
      <td>nothing</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

or

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <div class="hover">
      <tr>jhk
        <div class="tooltip">asdadasd
        </div>
        <td>nothing </td>
        <td>nothing</td>
        <td>nothing</td>
        <td>nothing</td>
        <td>nothing</td>
      </tr>
    </div>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This HTML works on its own [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8gC3D/4097/)

```
<div class="hover">
  jhk
  <div class="tooltip">asdadasd
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS that goes with it

```
.hover {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}

.tooltip {
  top: -10px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.hover:hover .tooltip {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Note: The css that is posted is the same css that is in the first two examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally we don't break the table format. So the **tooltip** content should be there in `td` tag

```
<table>
   <tr class="hover">
    <td>jhk
       <div class="tooltip">asdadasd</div>
    </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It is still not visible

Comment: @userlkjsflkdsvm top:-10px; hide the tooltip. If i set top:0; then its over lay in td tag :-(

Comment: I figured it out thanks, do you know if it would be possible when hovering over the tooltip content itself, I don't see that content? Basically I just want to hover over the row and the tooltip appear and nothing else

Answer (score 0):

Create invisible DIV for each row. This DIV will be your tooltip, it doesn't matter where it will be just make sure it won't be in the way.

Then use JavaScript to detect when (and where) you are over some row, then (using JS and CSS) show the right DIV (the one that have your tooltip text) next to the mouse pointer.